# Angular Js Flyout menu

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

This is my first project in angular js and i'm trying to show a tree in a flyout menu. I have found this dropdown menu example http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/website/tree.html and i want to change it to a Flyout menu.

So in the given example children nodes are displayed below the parent node. However, I want children nodes to be displayed on the right of parent.

Is there any example that i have missed?
What would be the best approch to do that knowing that the menu content will be loaded dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple a flyout menu using Angular. The content is not dynamic in the example, but the data model could be tweaked so that the contents of the menu are loaded dynamically.

http://codepen.io/jonnycincocinco/pen/dpovAB

```
.tree {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 150px; }
  .tree .currentItem {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 150px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    border-radius: 3px; }
    .tree .currentItem:hover {
      background-color: #f9f9f9; }
    .tree .currentItem > .arrow {
      top: 13px; }
    .tree .currentItem > ul {
      left: -1px;
      top: -5px; }
  .tree li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #7f7f7f;
    text-decoration: none; }
  .tree .arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px; }
    .tree .arrow.right {
      border-left-color: #7f7f7f; }
  .tree li a.active {
    background: #4285f4;
    color: white; }
    .tree li a.active > .arrow.right {
      border-left-color: white; }
  .tree ul {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    top: -11px;
    left: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
  .tree .active > ul {
    display: block; }
```